# Unity/Firestore Functions in JS: Invalid Type for conversion to variant - when passing a list of classes via a dictionary

Tags: javascript, c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function written in JS that creates a new game.

I'm sending in a list of PlayerInfo from Unity, but every time I get an error about my data received as being an Invalid Type.

I've tried multiple different approaches from the C# Unity side but every time I get returned an error of either

1st approach

```
"Error creating game invite: Invalid type System.Collections.Generic.List System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary System.String,System.String for conversion to Variant"
```

2nd approach

```
"Invalid type PlayerInfo for conversion to Variant"
```

- code for 1st C# approach

```
public async void CallCreateGameInvite()
{
     List Dictionary string, string  players = new List
    {
        new Dictionary { { "username", "Player1" }, { "userID", "userID1" } },
        new Dictionary { { "username", "Player2" }, { "userID", "userID2" } }
        // Add additional players here
    };

    await CreateGameInvite(players);
}
```

```
 private async Task CreateGameInvite(List<Dictionary<string, string>> players)
    {
        try
        {
            FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
            var func = functions.GetHttpsCallable("createGameInvite");
            var result = await func.CallAsync(new { players });

            Debug.Log("Game invite created with ID: "); //result.Data["gameID"]);
            // Use the gameID and perform further actions in your Unity project
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error creating game invite: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

- code for 2nd C# approach

```
List players = new List
{
    new PlayerInfo("Player1", "userID1"),
    new PlayerInfo("Player2", "userID2"),
};
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{

    public string username;
    public string userID;

    public PlayerInfo(string username, string userID)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

```
private async void CreateGameInvite(List players)
{
    try
    {
        var requestData = new Dictionary
        {
            { "players", players }
        };

        FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
        var func = functions.GetHttpsCallable("createGameInvite");
        var result = await func.CallAsync(requestData);

        Debug.Log("Game invite created with ID: " + result.Data);
        // Use the gameID and perform further actions in your Unity project
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error creating game invite: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

- Here is my code for the JS cloud function:

```
// Class for player information
class PlayerInfo 
{
    constructor(username, userID) {
      this.username = username;
      this.userID = userID;
    }
}

exports.createGameInvite = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try 
    {
        const gameID = generateUniqueGameID();
  
        // List of players
        const players = data.players; // Assuming that players are passed in the request data
  
        // Create a document in the Firestore collection named GameInvites
        const gameInviteRef = admin.firestore().collection('GameInvites').doc(gameID);
        await gameInviteRef.set({ players: players });
  
        // Add the game invite to UserGameInvites collection for each user ID
        players.forEach(player => { admin.firestore().collection('UserGameInvites').doc(player.userID).collection('invites').doc(gameID).set({ gameID: gameID });
     });
  
        return { gameID: gameID }; // Return the gameID as the result
      } catch (error) {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Error creating game invite', error);
      }
  });
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something about how parse the 'data' object in the JS I'm sending from Unity.

Would very much appreciate any help!(:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.The data you send from Unity should be serializable to JSON correctly.
2.The Cloud Function should be able to Deserialize the received JSON back into the expected JavaScript object structure.

For the first approach, you should serialize your list of dictionaries to JSON before sending it to the Cloud Function:

```
public async void CallCreateGameInvite()
{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> players = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", "Player1" }, { "userID", "userID1" } },
        new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", "Player2" }, { "userID", "userID2" } }
        // Add additional players here
    };

    await CreateGameInvite(players);
}

private async Task CreateGameInvite(List<Dictionary<string, string>> players)
{
    try
    {
        string jsonPlayers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(players); // Convert the players list to JSON
        FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
        var func = functions.GetHttpsCallable("createGameInvite");
        var result = await func.CallAsync(new { players = jsonPlayers });

        Debug.Log("Game invite created with ID: " + result.Data);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error creating game invite: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

For the second approach, make sure that PlayerInfo is serializable to JSON:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public string username;
    public string userID;

    public PlayerInfo(string username, string userID)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}

// When you're ready to send the data
private async void CreateGameInvite(List<PlayerInfo> players)
{
    try
    {
        string jsonPlayers = JsonUtility.ToJson(new { players = players }); // Wrap and convert players list to JSON
        FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
        var func = functions.GetHttpsCallable("createGameInvite");
        var result = await func.CallAsync(jsonPlayers);

        Debug.Log("Game invite created with ID: " + result.Data);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error creating game invite: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Your Cloud Function needs to parse the incoming JSON to reconstruct the list of PlayerInfo objects correctly:

```
exports.createGameInvite = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try 
    {
        const gameID = generateUniqueGameID();

        // Parse the JSON string back into JavaScript objects
        const players = JSON.parse(data.players);

        // Rest of your code...
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Error creating game invite', error);
    }
});
```

Ensure that you are sending and receiving the data in the correct format. Your Unity code should serialize the data structure into a JSON string that matches what your JavaScript function expects.

Lastly, always remember to validate and sanitize data on both ends to avoid any security issues.